# Replace constant names with his values

Tags: php, constants

how can replace tagged constant names to their values in string?
For example,

```
define('name', 'Evgeny');
echo foo('[verb], dear [name]');
# Must be '[verb], dear Evgeny' or '[something], dear Evgeny'
```

Solved. Next works very good:

```
function foo($s) {
    $m = array();
    preg_match_all('/(\[[^\]]+\])/', $s, $m);
    $m = $m[0];
    print_r($m);
    $v = array();
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($m); $i++) {
        $name = substr($m[$i], 1, -1);
        $v[$i] = defined($name) ? constant($name) : '!' . $name . '!';
    }
    return str_replace($m, $v, $s);
}

define('name', 'Evgeny');
$str = '[verb], dear [name]';
echo foo($str);
```

Returns '!verb!, dear Evgeny'

Comment: Want to make this function foo

Comment: `define('name', 'Evgeny');
$str = '[verb], dear [name]';
echo foo($str);`

Answer (score 0):

```
define('name', 'Evgeny');
echo '[verb], dear ', name;
```

use it by itself, don't wrap it in quotes

Comment: I wasn't trying to pass it to `foo()`, just showing him how to use constants.

Comment: I know. My point is that he wants to send the string to `foo()`. If he used the string as you've placed it above, the comma concat character would cause serious issues ;)

Comment: I know what he is trying to do, and it is still his job to change it to his needs not copy/paste.

Answer (score 0):

What about:

```
echo foo('[verb], dear '.name);
```

Comment: I do not know what will be in line :)

Answer (score 0):

You would use:

```
echo foo( '[verb], dear ' . name );
```

Comment: Please upvote answers already posted. Rather than duplicating them.

Comment: The answer already posted was invalid. I was in the process of commenting on your answer to make you aware of the error.

Comment: You had a dot and single quote on the end of name.